# focus on input in sticky bar force page to scroll to top

Tags: html, css, mobile, focus, responsive

I have the following situation:
responsive site, sticky header and search input in the sticky header.

The problem appears on phone & tablet when I scroll the page and click the search input, it focus on the input field and show the phone keyboard and scroll the page to where the input field is in the DOM (which is in the beginning of my html code)

How to prevent scrolling to top, and have focus on my search bar?
I'm not sure if I've explained it clearly. That's why I'm attaching a video with the problem - https://youtu.be/7UOiDmEvp4U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns that there is a bug with position fixed in iOS 8+

Here's what I used to fix the problem: https://gist.github.com/AlexanderOMara/8747f59b6450878e78c7

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to set `e.preventDefault();`. Maybe the code below helps you.

```js
$(function() {
  $('nav').on('click', '.search', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $el = $(e.currentTarget);
    
    $el.find('input').addClass('large').focus();
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 600px;
}
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}
.search .fa {
  cursor: pointer;
 }
.search input {
  width: 50px;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.search input.large {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
  <div class="search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    <input>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but unfortunately it does exactly the same thing as shown in the video :(